# Require.JS in a Chrome extension: define is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, scope, requirejs

I'm trying to use Requre.js in my chrome extension.

Here is my manifest:

```
{
    "name":"my extension",
    "version":"1.0",
    "manifest_version":2,
    "permissions": ["http://localhost/*"],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "js/test.js"
    ],
    "content_scripts":[
        {           
            "matches":["http://localhost/*"],
            "js":[
                "js/require.js",
                "js/hd_init.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

hd_init.js

```
console.log("hello, i'm init");

require.config({
    baseUrl: chrome.extension.getURL("js")
});

require( [ "js/test"], function ( ) {
    console.log("done loading");
});
```

js/test.js

```
console.log("hello, i'm test");
define({"test_val":"test"});
```

This is what I get in console:

```
hello, i'm init chrome-extension://bacjipelllbpjnplcihblbcbbeahedpo/js/hd_init.js:8
hello, i'm test test.js:8
**Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined test.js:2**
done loading
```

So it loads the file, but can't see "define" function.
This looks like some kind of a scope error.
If I run in on local server, it works as it should.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two contexts in content scripts. One is for browser, another is for extension.

You load require.js into the extension context. But require.js loads dependencies into the browser context. `define` is not defined in the browser.

I wrote a (untested) patch about this problem. To use this, load this into extension context  after require.js. Your modules will be loaded into extension context. Hope this helps.

```
require.attach = function (url, context, moduleName, onScriptLoad, type, fetchOnlyFunction) {
  var xhr;
  onScriptLoad = onScriptLoad || function () {
    context.completeLoad(moduleName);
  };
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      eval(xhr.responseText);
      onScriptLoad();
    }
  };
  xhr.send(null);
};
```

Comment: The only thing I would change there, is to add sourceURL for eval, to make debugging more pleasant:   `eval(xhr.responseText + "//@ sourceURL=" + url );`

Comment: The recommended approach now is to use cajon ( https://github.com/requirejs/cajon/ ). See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/requirejs/elU_NYjunRw/3NT9NIFL2GUJ .

Comment: Does this approach still work with modern versions of Chrome? I can't quite seem to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach now is to use cajon ( https://github.com/requirejs/cajon/ ). See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/requirejs/elU_NYjunRw/3NT9NIFL2GUJ .